# What does "Balls to bones" mean?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix (1999)* Oracle says to Neo:

> Sentence: "Being the one is like being in love. No one can tell
> you're in love, you just know it. Through and through. **Balls to
> bones**.

What does "Balls to bones" mean?

Comment: I assume he means 'from your genitals right through to your skeleton'.

Comment: @KateBunting The Oracle in 'The Matrix' is a female character. But I agree with your interpretation.  (It is just a more colourful way of repeating what she said in the previous sentence: "Through and through".)